# How to set a variable from different class when the activity is first time loaded?

Tags: android, class, variables, button, checked

I'm beginner in Java Android developing. I'm using Eclipse SDK 3.6.1 version. I'm trying to this: first class is watching a two RadioButtons status from second class. I'm trying to set RadioButton status when they are not clicked.

First class:

```
public void onClick(View view) {        
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.Button01:         
        if (toolsas.rb1.isChecked()) { //do something
```

Second class with RadioButtons:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {


        case R.id.RadioButton01:
            rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
            rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton02);

            if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                rb2.setChecked(false);
                rb1.setChecked(true);
```

When I click a RadioButton rb1 and change him status to checked the first class is working, bet how to set status when I don't click RadioButton rb1? If I firstable click Button01 the program is stopped. First class have few buttons, when I push the Button01 I can call a second class and change some options
Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty hard to figure out what you are trying to do, but I **think** you have two different layouts, each of which has a different radio button.  I think you want them to have opposite status, so that when a user checks one, the other will appear unchecked?

If so, one way to do this is to save the state of the checkboxes to `SharedPreferences`.  Whenever the user changes the setting of a checkbox, save its state into `SharedPreferences`.  Whenever you load one of your `Activites` you can then read the value from your preferences and set the UI to match.

- [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
- [SharedPreferences reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: But if I want automaticly set RadioButton to checked status before I start the program. First I load main.java class (the main layout), RadioButton is in toolsas.java class. If want to do something I have to go to toolsas.java class and checked the RadioButton rb1. If I dont checked the RadioButton rb1 program is crashed cause RadioButton have not status. SharedPreferences is it best way to resolve the problem?

Comment: @Juronis Still not sure I fully understand you, but yes, I think `SharedPreferences` is the way to go.  In your `onResume()` method of `toolsas` you read the value in from the preferences and set your UI.  The data storage link I provided has some example code.